# I am trying to run apache server under a server using /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k start

Tags: apache

I am trying to run apache server under a server using /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k start but the output i am getting is /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl :no such directory or file. Can anyone help me . thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you install Apache? If you don't know the answer, how did you install apache?

Comment: i installed apache on this path only /usr/local/apache2 but still its showing this error

Comment: then what does `find /usr/local/apache2 -name apachectl` tell you?

Comment: ok there is change in my quesion now.. when i am trying to copy a local directory to remote server directory. it is asking for remote server password but i dint set any password for that..how should i solve it??